# Erase/Undelete in salesforce Lightning?

Tags: lightning, recycle-bin, undelete

Is there a Erase/Undelete option in salesforce Lightning. I was trying to find out Erase a deleted Field then i couldnt find it. I know its there in Classic version. Let me know where I can find this option in Lightning

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I am aware, this feature is not supported in Lightning UI yet.

Here is an idea: [Lightning Experience - Recycle Bin](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000DsAuAAK), which we can vote and after sufficient votes maybe Salesforce product team would plan to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

We are pleased to announce that our application “[Recycle Bin Manager][1]" is available for FREE on App-exchange now. You can now restore your record directly from Lightning Experience without switching to the Classic UI.

Recycle Bin Manager also lets you:
 1) Search for deleted records by filtering based an Object, Deleted by User and Date range. 
 2) Preview the deleted records data before restoring it. 
 3) Permanently delete the unwanted records from the recycle bin.